# Parsing User Agents in GO (Golang) - Tobie/ua-parser

Tags: ruby, regex, go, user-agent

I am trying to stream (a lot) of user agents through a GO (Golang) program to extract different information about these ua agents like device type, OS, etc.

The GO code in Tobie Langel's UA Parser Repo looks very promising:

https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser/tree/master/go/uaparser

I created a simple program, in which I basically add streaming functionality to the example on the README page.  To compare performance, I created the same type of simple program with a Ruby gem that uses a similar approach and same regexes.yaml file.

https://github.com/toolmantim/user_agent_parser

After compiling the Go program and testing both, the Ruby version is running 2-3 times faster than the GO version.

As far as I can see, both programs are loading and processing the ua agents in a similar manner.

I am new to GO and am wondering if anyone sees any major optimizations or fixes that could make programs using the GO portion of this repo run faster.

I am also interested to know if anyone knows of any other GO libraries I can use to parse user agents that work well.

---TESTING SIMPLE PROGRAMS TO COMPARE REGEX VS PCRE LIBS (as suggested in the comments below)

I have created the programs below, one using PCRE and one using the standard regex library.  However, I don't seem to be getting a performance boost with PCRE.  In fact, the PCRE library seems to be a little slower.  Am I approaching this the wrong way?

--With standard regex library

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "regexp"
  "strings"
  "bufio"
  "os"
)

func main() {

  var regex = regexp.MustCompile(`Mac`)
  scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

  for scanner.Scan() {

    line := scanner.Text()
    fields := strings.Split(line, "\t")
    fmt.Println(regex.FindIndex([]byte(fields[0])))

  }

}
```

--With PCRE library

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  pcre "github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre/src/pkg/pcre"
  "bufio"
  "os"
  "strings"
)

func main() {

  scanner:= bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
  var regex = pcre.MustCompile(`Mac`, 0)

  for scanner.Scan() {

    line := scanner.Text()
    fields := strings.Split(line, "\t")
    fmt.Println(regex.FindIndex([]byte(fields[0]),0))

 }
}
```

Comment: Go's `regexp` library isn't as fast in the average case as some languages' libraries. You could `go get` a package with [PCRE bindings](https://github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre) then modify the UA parser to use it. Unless _absolute_ performance is bad, I'm not sure I'd bother.

Comment: If you're curious, Go's library follows a different model (NFAs)--the current implementation is slower than Perl's in some common cases but less likely to hang on a bad regexp/text combination. You can read (a lot) more here: http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of using PCRE bindings in GO?

Comment: Looks like a similar interface as the builtin one:
http://godoc.org/github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre/src/pkg/pcre

Comment: I edited the original question with a couple of small examples. One using PCRE and one using the standard regex library. However, I don't seem to be getting a performance boost with PCRE. In fact, the PCRE library seems to be a little slower. Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: Since PCRE is using `[]byte`s you should use `scanner.Bytes()` and `bytes.Split()`. [ua-parser's regexes.yaml](https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser/blob/master/regexes.yaml) actually seems to have a lot of regexes to cover rare browsers; you could probably get by with just a handful of them (to detect the major browsers) for your purposes. If you really did want to tune the daylights out of this, you could split the input into 1k-line chunks that you feed to a bunch of goroutines running in parallel, but not sure that's worth it.

Comment: Using scanner.Bytes() doesn't seem to speed it up much.  I agree there are a lot of regexes in the yaml file that are adding more overhead than value, but I would prefer to not alter this file.  Using Ruby is still an option for me.  I prefer to use GO, but I would have to get performance to at least be comparable to Ruby or Python.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider the [rubex](https://github.com/moovweb/rubex) library. I changed ua-parser to use rubex instead, and I saw a 7x speed improvement. The library claims a 10x improvement, so I would give it a try with your particular application.

Comment: I tried streaming user agents to a simple program like the ones above using rubex.  It was faster, but more in the 10% range.